# How to pay rent fee when creating solana wallet in nodejs

Tags: node.js, solana, solana-web3js

hello I create solana wallet with the following code on my nodejs server.

```
const SolanaWeb3 = require("@solana/web3.js"); 
SolanaWeb3.Keypair.generate();
```

I don't think this is an active wallet. Because I haven't paid the rent fee for this account.

**So I want to know when is the moment when this inactive account pays the rent fee.
(I want to know if it is activated when a transaction in which sol is deposited into this account occurs, or whether this account should generate a transaction that sends solana to another place.)

And I want to know if there is a javascript function that gives rent fee when account is created.**

thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***To your second question***

> And I want to know if there is a javascript function that gives rent fee when account is created

Yes there is. Assuming you just want a system account that holds SOL versus an account that has data:

```js
  // amount of space to reserve for the account. system accounts are 0 space
  const space = 0;

  // Get the rent, in lamports, for exemption
  const rentExemptionAmount =
    await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(space);
```

***To your first question***

If you already have a funded account (`fromKeyPair`), you can use that accounts public key to fund the new account you want to create:

```js
  const newAccountKeypair = SolanaWeb3.Keypair.generate();

  const createAccountParams = {
    fromPubkey: fromKeyPair.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: newAccountKeypair.publicKey,
    lamports: rentExemptionAmount,
    space,
    programId: SolanaWeb3.SystemProgram.programId,
  };


  const createAccountTransaction = new SolanaWeb3.Transaction().add(
    SolanaWeb3.SystemProgram.createAccount(createAccountParams)
  );

  await SolanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, createAccountTransaction, [
    fromKeyPair,
    newAccountKeypair,
  ]);
```

Comment: Great answer but I still have some doubts:
1. if I create a wallet using a client like phantom I’d assume it only creates a pub/private key pair, but it doesn’t create a wallet on chain since there’s no one to pay the rent, right? 
2. If I get some sol from an exchange, and transfer to this account that is not on chain, what happens? Cause Binance wont be sending a “createAccountTransaction”, will it?